# trigger function js when save button admin product is clicked magento

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to trigger a function in js when clicking on save button in edit product admin page. I followed the suggestions from here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119542/calling-js-function-when-product-save-button-is-clicked

And I modify in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php

$this->setChild('save_button',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Save'),
                    'onclick'   => 'productForm.submit(); myFunction();',
                    'class' => 'save'
                ))
        );
```

But I don't know in which template should I put the myFunction(). I tried in

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml
```

and

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/admintheme/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml


function myFunction(){
    console.log('test');
}
```

but with no success. So my question is: where should I put the function in order to be activated when the save button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

This got long as a comment, so I've added it as an answer:

### Conjecture:

Your scoping might be off. Add it to a top-level page like: `index.html`, then you can assign the function as:

```
window.myFunction = () => console.log('test')
```

Since window is a global variable, you should have access to it from your `click` handler!

### Hypothesis 2

You could actually be putting the function in files that do not import at/before the `click` handler is triggered. (*this seems a bit less probable*)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code here `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\index\notifications.phtml`